# Changing css in code works only once

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create a question game, basically if the question is correct it pops an image with a green check if it's wrong it pops a red X.
I've set both images on hidden and when the question is answered it changes the css to visible and also changes the src name to the one needed and then it does a fadeout but it's only working once.. I'm guessing it's only working once because the css has been changed to visible and it remains on visible while faded out.. I tried changing it back to hidden but that didn't work.. I'm sorry if such a question exists before kinda been looking around and didn't find an answer.

any additional advice is highly appreciated since I am still learning, thank you.

```js
var questions = [
    ["question", "yes"],
    ["question2", "no"]
    ];

var max = questions.length -1;
pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
//document.write(pos);

function questioner (){

var question1 = questions[pos][0];
    document.getElementById("questionquote").innerHTML = question1;
        
}

var correct = 0;
function check (){
    var answer = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var answerL = answer.toLowerCase();
    //var areEqual = question1.toUpperCase() === questions[pos][1].toUpperCase();
    if (answerL !=null && answerL !== ''){
    if (answerL == questions[pos][1]){
        //$(".test").show();
        
        $("#result").attr("src","correct.jpg");
        $(".correct_answer").css("visibility", "visible");
        $('.correct_answer').fadeOut(3000);
        correct++;
        //delete questions[pos];
        questions.splice(pos, 1);
        var max = questions.length -1;
        //window.prompt(questions); //testing the array deletion
        pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        
        
    document.getElementById("number_correct").className = "green";
    
    }

    else {
        correct--;
        document.getElementById("number_correct").className = "red";
        $("#result").attr("src","wrong.png");
        $(".correct_answer").css("visibility", "visible");
        $('.correct_answer').fadeOut(3000);
    }

}
//$(".correct_answer").css("visibility", "hidden");
questioner ();

    
    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + correct;
    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    $('#quiz')[0].reset();
    
}

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  q
```

```css
 .correct_answer {
    visibility: hidden;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
       
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   

  
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
<script src= "questions"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
        <h1 class="title">Quote Game!</h1>
        <div class="container">
        <form id="quiz" name="quiz" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <container class="cont1">
            
        <p class="questionp">Which hero does this quote belong to? </p>
        <div class="row">
           
        <!--<div class="form-group float-label-control">-->
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <p class="question"  id="questionquote"></p>  
       </div> 

        <div class="col-6 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ">
                <p id = "number_correct" class="green"></p>
                </div>
        
                <script class="score">document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "Your Score: " + correct;</script>
             
                 <div class="col-6 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                    <img src="transparent.gif" height="90" width="90" class="pull-right">
                    </div>
            
       
            
              <input class="form-control" id="question1" name="question1" placeholder="Hero Name" onclick="IsEmpty();"  ">
        <br> </br>

     
       <!--<input class="answer" id="question1" name="question1"></input><br> </br>-->
        </div> 
        <input id="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Check" onclick = "check();">
    </div>
</container>
        </form>
 

<img id="result" class="correct_answer" src="" height="130" width="90%">
<!--<img class="wrong_answer" src="wrong.png" height="130" width="90%">-->


<!-- this code is for testing purposes it is not needed in the actual code -->  
<!--<p id="demo"></p>
    

<button onclick="x()">Try it</button> --> 

</body>

</html>


<script>
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() { return false; });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to correct your syntax errors first. Also, consider keeping each question/answer in an object and all the objects in an array.